# Drawing 3D points in Java

Tags: java, 3d, drawing, points

My question is - how to draw 3D points in java? I would like to make some plot in simply way. I' ve tried to used it:
http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php
but there is no documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The Java 3D API is an application programming interface used for writing three-dimensional graphics applications and applets.

for more details go there http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.4.0/javax/media/j3d/doc-files/intro.html

example
http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.4.0/javax/media/j3d/doc-files/HelloUniverse.html